# Question about multiple 'root' users in mysql's users table

Tags: mysql

```
+-----------+------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| host      | user             | password                                  |
+-----------+------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| localhost | root             | *bunch of gibberish                       |
| localhost | phpmyadmin       | *bunch of gibberish                       |
| 127.0.0.1 | root             | *bunch of gibberish                       |
| ::1       | root             | *bunch of gibberish                       |
| localhost | debian-sys-maint | *bunch of gibberish                       |
+-----------+------------------+-------------------------------------------+
```

So I did `use mysql;` and then `select host, user, password from user;`

It seems like there are multiple roots, a phpmyadmin, a debian-sys-maint, etc. Is this normal? Should I be deleting any of these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's three entries there because you need one entry for each `user@host` combination.

Examine `host` for each of the `root` user entries.  The `host` column defines where that user can connect from and have the connection accepted.  In this case, for the `root` user, the host entries are `localhost`, `127.0.0.1`, and `::1`.  The last two are IPv4 and IPv6 entries for the local machine loopback interface (`lo` in `ifconfig`) respectively.  The `localhost` entry is the hostname representation of both of those IP entries.

It's fine to leave all three there.  It just makes sure that you can still access the root user from the local system in the event that your `/etc/hosts` file goes weird and `localhost` no longer resolves to your own box.

The only thing you *really* need to be concerned about is if a `root` user on MySQL has an entry for any `host` entry OTHER than `localhost`, `127.0.0.1`, and `::1`.  That could indicate a security risk.

And the `debian-sys-maint` account is used for log rotating and things, and just like the root account can only be used via localhost in a default setup, so you don't need to really worry about that one either.

Comment: What about debian-sys-maint? Also when would localhost ever not resolve to my own box?

Comment: @user51819 `debian-sys-maint` is used by the operating system, for logfile stuff (see [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/9948/what-is-the-debian-sys-maint-mysql-user-and-more)), and you can leave it there as well.

Comment: But if I were a hacker, wouldn't I try to exploit some sort of security hole by taking advantage of a default account like debian-sys-maint?

Comment: @user51819 You need to leave that user in the system in order to let `logrotate` rotate the log files.  Besides, you need to *again* look at the `host` entry.  It only works from `localhost`.  If a hacker has broken into your system and has access to `localhost` there's a LOT more to worry about than your MySQL database.  The default users have been looked at by the security team for consideration of that, anyways, `root` has to exist for MySQL to exist.  `debian-sys-maint`, to my knowledge, only can work with logfiles, but don't quote me on that.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the point of the "host" component. That means that particular user can only work if the host of the person logged in is localhost? So that would imply the only way someone could be using these accounts is to somehow gain root (e.g. SSHing into my box or something)

Comment: @user51819 correct.  If you had an entry for `thomasw` under user, and under `host` it had only `localhost` that means I have to gain access to your computer and connect from a local connection (or an SSH-tunneled connection) before the system would let me in.  `host` indicates where that user can login from, and if `host` doesn't match (or the `host` is not a wildcard to act as a 'catch-all'), then it denies the auth

Comment: Strange that it shows the password hashes as being equivalent in a few cases -- makes me wonder if they're not being salted?

Comment: @user51819 Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15501/discussion-between-thomas-w-and-user51819).